# External Java Library issue with Autowiring and injecting bean

Tags: spring, maven, javabeans

I have created a Spring Boot application managed by Maven.
I'm retrieving an company's library from our Maven repository.

In this library, we have a service interface, not being annotated with '@Service':

```
public interface MyService {
   //...
}
```

This service has only one implementation :

```
public class DefaultMyService implements MyService {
   //...
}
```

This library context is managed the old Spring way (in applicationContext.xml file).
I read that normally, Spring Boot is able to find the implementation if there's only one in the scope.

When I try to run "spring-boot:run" on my project, it will fail with the following error :

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.pharmagest.saml.SAMLService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I tried:

1. To add a @ComponentScan on the configuration class, including packages in error : `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.mycompany.web", "com.mycompany.thelibrary.client.*", "com.mycompany.thelibrary.services.*"})`
2. To add the bean definition in applicationContext.xml (if I add the interface it tells me it can define it, thus I heard that Spring can find the default implementation if there is only one ?)
3. To add library at "runtime" in projects options
4. To add the library as external resource not via maven

In all cases I just can maven build but can't run the project.
Do you have any advice to help me ? thanks!

Comment: For option 2, can you show your definition in applicationContext.xml?

Comment: Can't you just create the bean manually and mark the method as @Bean to return the instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Won't work as the `DefaultMyService` has no `@Component` (or `@Service`) annotation will not be detected.
2. Bean definition has to be a concrete instance so use `DefaultMyService` instead of the interface. Spring will not detect anything for you your understanding is wrong
3. and 4. Will not change anything only adding dependencies without proper 1. or 2. will do nothing.

Just add a `@Bean` to your configuration

```
@Bean
public DefaultMyService myService() {
    return new DefaultMyService();
}
```

Or import the other libraries `applicatiponContext.xml` which is what you probably should do.

```
@ImportResource("classpath:/applicationContext.xml")
```

Add this next to the `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: Hi, I did it. I've imported the applicationContext.xml file :( And I can't have the source of the library. I'm forced to use it as-is. So I can't add "@service" or @Bean

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to add `@Bean`. I you can `@ImportResource` to a class you can add an `@Bean` to that same class as well.

Comment: oh yeah sorry I though you were asking me to add @Bean on the service itself my bad

Comment: Yeah I did this and it solved the problem, I'm ashamed I didn't spotted that ... anyway I have other errors now probably due to the fact that my applicationContext.xml file can't retrieve values from my application.yml conf file :) thanks

Comment: please do not import magic beans injection from libraries configurations. In my experience, this is really difficult to maintain, as you always need to have in mind from where those "magic" beans are being injected. I prefer to define the beans in the application configuration and have some kind of factory in the library.